# What are unaccented letters called?

Tags: accent, diacritics

Does anyone know the technical name for letters without accents glyphs etc? Like what's the opposite of diacritic? Grapheme? Thanks for your advice.

```
amoré
```

é vs e

Comment: If you’re talking about them in connection with diacritics, you could call them _base letters_ (meaning ‘the letter itself before you add the diacritics’). That won’t work, though, if you just want a general word to refer to letters, but exclude ones with diacritics.

Comment: Be aware that while in some languages é is just an e with an accent and may just mark that it is stressed or pronounced at all, in other languages thys sybol is a different letter (e.g., a long e). Diacritic symbols like č should not be reffered to as accents at all and in languages that use these the letters with diacritics are often separate letters, for different sounds, with their own place in the alphabet (ABCČDĎ...).

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is "Latin (Roman) letter", referring to the letters used by write Latin – which did not use those diacritics. This excludes all modern inventions like <ŋ ɓ ɔ ʕ>. Or, "base letter". There is no single word. People often say "letter" to mean the things without diacritics, but there is no "technical" word, instead, if you want to be technical, you would describe exactly what you mean. Even then, [ñ](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%91) is apparently described in Spanish as a "letra", even though is includes a diacritic.